# Which font is this and how can I use it in latex?

Tags: fonts

I would like to know which font the following image is:

[image]

and how to use it in latex. Any ideas?
It is not quite Times.

Comment: These are two seperate questions. 1. What is this font? and 2. How can I use it in `LaTeX`. As answer to the first, you could use "WhatTheFont" at https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ to recognise the font from an image. Your second question can be approached in two ways, depending on which engine or what ease of use has your preference. The easier solution uses `fontspec` through either the XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX engine. If you only wish to use `pdfLaTeX` (the "default" engine if you will), you should take a look at `otftotfm`, which installs your fonts and makes them accessible in any engine.

Comment: @1010011010 Well it does depend on what the font turns out to be! If the font turns out to be type1 or truetype or, even, metafont, `otftotfm` is not going to do the job. (I am guessing you recognise the font and so know it is opentype but your comment suggests `otftotfm` is a viable strategy for any font, which is not the case.